# How to Site-to-siteVPN into Office with Office router connected to home router

Tags: networking, vpn

I've got the task to create a VPN tunnel to our Server here at the Office. He has multiple devices, and changes them due to being a developer. Therefore we opted for a Site-to-Site VPN. But this Router will be connected to his Home router. How would I solve this?

Would it be possible to turn off NAT on the router, and only encapsulate the traffic going to the office?

We use Ubiquiti routers, and I've made a pretty little topologi to make this easier to overview .

[image: Topologi]

Comment: OpenVPN would be the preferred method, however, I'm not familiar with the Ubiquiti interface.  I can provide an OpenVPN server and client config that will do what you want, but I'm unsure if you'd be able to natively apply it via Ubiquiti's WebUI

Comment: I've already have a OpenVPN server running at our ER-8 (office router). I will try and connect to that.

Comment: Just an FYI, most use generic configs pulled from the internet for OpenVPN which is an efficient way to set up OpenVPN as the configs should be tuned to get the best throughput and security.  For example, many use `AES-256-CBC` for encryption when it's wholly unnecessary since AES128 will remain uncrackable for some time _(lowering the rekey values would be a better alternative, i.e. 5min / 100mb as an example)_.  Tuned config [examples](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN)